# Change movie clip colour based on percentage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a grid of circles, 25 in total and they represent a percentage. I will have a series of projects with different percentages so want to create a template where I simply input a number (percentage) that that change the colour of that proportion of the mcs.

To change their colour I am doing the following:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dot_changer);
function dot_changer(event:Event):void
{
    import fl.motion.Color;
    var c:Color = new Color();
    c.setTint(0xff0000, 0.8);
    this.dot1.transform.colorTransform = c;
    this.dot2.transform.colorTransform = c;
    this.dot3.transform.colorTransform = c;
    this.dot4.transform.colorTransform = c;
}
```

The reason I am using an enterFrame and not a button is these need to simply play without any user input or interruption.

I was thinking of having an if statement that checks a var holding my percentage and assigning a cut off value to each dot mc. for example dot25 will only change colour if the var value is below 96

There must be an easier or more logical way.

Comment: I keep receiving notifications from this thread, but I see no updates - what's going on? :)

Comment: trying to do this from my phone. not working too well. my appologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object and a for loop and minimize the whole thing a great lot:

```
package {
    import fl.motion.Color;
    public class QuickTint extends Color {
        public function QuickTint(tintColor:uint, tintMultiplier:Number) {
            setTint(tintColor, tintMultiplier);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// Do this once - place it outside your function
var thresholds:Object = {
    dot25: 96
};
var defaultThreshold:int = 50;
var colourDefault:QuickTint = new QuickTint(0xff0000, 0.8);
var colourThreshold:QuickTint = new QuickTint(0x0000ff, 0.8);

// Do this whenever you want to check the colours
var dotName:String;
var threshold:int;
for (var i:uint = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    dotName = "dot" + i;
    threshold = (thresholds.hasOwnProperty(dotName) ? thresholds[dotName] : defaultThreshold);

    if (value >= threshold) {
        this[dotName].transform.colorTransform = colourThreshold;
    } else {
        this[dotName].transform.colorTransform = colourDefault;
    }
}
```

`value` needs to be your value. `colourThreshold` will be the `Color` if it's the same of above your threshold (eg 96), and `colourDefault` will be the `Color` that it should have by default.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. The only problem ( and sure is due to my inexperience) is I get an Error #1034: Type Coercion failed when trying to set colour values for colourThreshold and colourDefault.

Comment: @user2996529 Could you update your OP with your new code? (The code where you've defined `value`, `colourThreshold` and `colourDefault`)

Comment: 'code' var value = 66;
 var  colourThreshold = (0x0000ff);
 var colourDefault = (0x0000ff);'code'

Comment: @user2996529 The problem is that your colours aren't part of the `Color` class. I've added a `QuickTint` class that you can use to quickly create these (just create `QuickTint.as`) or you can create it like you did in your question.